# Figma python API response: 404 - Cannot POST

Tags: python, api, http-status-code-404, figma

I'm trying to use the Figma Python API to create a rectangle.
I get 404 - Cannot POST.
Do you have any idea what is the problem?
I tried to check the access token and the file id are valid.

```py
def create_rectangle(token, file_id, name, width, height, fill_color):
    url = f"https://api.figma.com/v1/files/{file_id}/components"

    headers = {
        "X-Figma-Token": token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }

    payload = {
        "name": name,
        "type": "RECTANGLE",
        "absoluteBoundingBox": {"width": width, "height": height},
        "fills": [{"type": "SOLID", "color": {"r": 22, "g": 22, "b": 22, "a": 1}}],
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "SVG Image",
                "type": "FRAME",
                "absoluteBoundingBox": {"width": 70, "height": 70},
                "fills": [{"type": "SOLID", "color": fill_color}],
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "SVG Content",
                        "type": "VECTOR",
                        "vectorPaths": [
                            {
                                "d": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0b/Card_heart.svg",
                                "isClosed": True,
                            }
                        ],
                    }
                ],
            }
        ],
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        print(f"Error creating rectangle: {response.status_code}")
        return None


def main():
    create_rectangle(FIGMA_API_TOKEN, FIGMA_FILE_ID, NAME, RECTANGLE_WIDTH, RECTANGLE_HEIGHT, SVG_FILL_COLOR)
```